# Flutter dialog doesn't make system navigation bar transparent

Tags: flutter, dialog, navbar, alert

In native apps when an alert or dialog is opened, the status bar and system navigation bar become transparent but in flutter system navigation bar stays white..please help me to achieve this.

In native apps:

[image]

In flutter:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question & post a few examples or screen shot so that we may understand better.

Comment: I did.please take a look now

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set variables in your AppTheme and modify variables when dialog open.

Comment: Here a gist, look for comments:
https://gist.github.com/BLKKKBVSIK/703a0bf9f61140b1137d9e2246d67aeb

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots now.please take a look

Comment: Oh sorry I through you were speaking about the status bar, where is the battery indicator.
I'll delete my answer in a few minutes

Comment: Alright.. How to alter system navbar then

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue in current flutter 3.19.x

i use SystemChrome to change color of system navigation bar but it color changing transtion have no animating/transition so it will be not sync